# Contar a quantidade de dias úteis do mês atual com mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Boa noite pessoal. Meu primeiro post mas vamos la.
Precioso montar uma consulta no mongoDB que me retorne a quantidade de dias úteis do mês atual. Exemplo: StartDate: 2022-03-01, EndDate: 2022-03-15.
Considerando o StartDate e EndDate teríamos 11 dias úteis.

Consegui trazer a quantidade de dias, mas não os dias uteis com a seguinte consulta:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateField": new Date()
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "MQL_CURRENT_MONTH": {
        "$dayOfMonth": "$dateField"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Resultado da consulta:

```
[
  {
    "MQL_CURRENT_MONTH": 15
  }
]
```

Com essa condição, consigo ver que hoje (15/03/2022) temos até o momento 15 dias. O que preciso agora é que considere apenas os dias úteis.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/1WdSLSuWQd2

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252173/12195738) do Stack Overflow em inglês atende sua necessidade, por favor. Se for o caso posso trazer a resposta para cá traduzida.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada @Rfroes87 obrigado por compartilhar

Comment: Acho que encontrei um método mais simples usando o a função $dateDiff do mongo. Basicamente o que eu faço: Conto quantos sábados e domingos existem para um determinado período, e subtraio pela quantidade de dias do mês atual.
[Veja o código](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YTAr1GTaCPK)
@Rfroes87

Comment: Bacana, acabei de testar e parece estar funcionando bem! Se tiver interesse, considere escrever uma resposta — detalhada, seguindo as diretrizes do [site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow).